# How to display multiple varied states for multiple radio groups?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, semantic-ui

Currently using Semantic-UI-React in a form, and want to use multiple Radio sections in said form. In the SUIR example code, the selected radio button displays as a title via state, however I want to have multiple groupings of radio selection options that show the corresponding selected button value. How do I change the current writing for state to be able to reflect ONLY the selected radio value for the option grouping it is apart of?

I have tried adding and id attribute to the Radio element, and then changed the display title from {this.state.value} to {this.id.state.value}, but of course that does not work.

// Here is my state declaration:

```
state = {};
  handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ value });
```

// The display title:

```
<Form.Field>
  Category:
  <b style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>{this.state.value}</b>
</Form.Field>
```

//Grid row that displays the various radio options:

```
<Grid.Row id="Category" columns={4}>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Radio
                    label="Health & Wellness"
                    name="radioGroup"
                    value="Health & Wellness"
                    checked={this.state.value === "Health & Wellness"}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Radio
                    label="Finance"
                    name="radioGroup"
                    value="Finance"
                    checked={this.state.value === "Finance"}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Radio
                    label="Culture"
                    name="radioGroup"
                    value="Culture"
                    checked={this.state.value === "Culture"}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Radio
                    label="Other"
                    name="radioGroup"
                    value="Other"
                    checked={this.state.value === "Other"}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </Grid.Column>
              </Grid.Row>
```

This is copy and pasted again beneath for an additional radio grouping.

I expect the first  to reference the relative selected value, and the second in the additional group to do the same, however when selecting any radio button in either group, the state reflects the selection value in both  elements.

Comment: here an example how to fix it: https://codesandbox.io/embed/green-river-oftnv

Answer (score 0):

Use the `name` of each group as a property in state

```
state = {group1: null, group2: null};
handleChange = (e, {name, value }) => this.setState({[name]: value });
```

Two different group items:

```
            /* group 1 */
            <Grid.Column>
              <Radio
                label="Finance"
                name="group1"
                value="Finance"
                checked={this.state.group1 === "Finance"}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </Grid.Column>
            /* group2 */
            <Grid.Column>
              <Radio
                label="Culture"
                name="group2"
                value="Culture"
                checked={this.state.group2 === "Culture"}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </Grid.Column>
```

Comment: why? What behaviour does the Radio Component have that breaks what he has?